# Call Sharepoint APIs from localhost

Tags: javascript, localhost, cross-domain, sharepoint-api

This thread is very similar to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035221/use-sharepoint-cross-domain-javascript-library-to-consume-rest-api-from-localhos) but I am not convinced by the answer given ("The library can't be used if the application is not deployed on the same sharepoint site domain") because in this page [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint/) the author insists on the fact that it is possible via the object `SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl)`.

So I followed all the steps mentionned in the page and I ended up with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent("https://lpl.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPortail"); 
  var appweburl = decodeURIComponent("http://localhost"); 
  var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

  // Load the .js file using jQuery's getScript function. 
  $.getScript( hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", continueExecution );

  function continueExecution() { 
      var executor; 

      // Initialize your RequestExecutor object. 
      executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl); 
      console.log(executor); // just to see if created

      // You can issue requests here using the executeAsync method 
      // of the RequestExecutor object.
      executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/title?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
        console.log('Successfully obtained data.');
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('There is an error.');
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  } 
});
```

When I executed it from localhost I get this:

[image]

I have been looking for the solution for 2 days. Maybe it is because the localhost is not a https, but even with this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost) I have not managed to do it (wamp won't start).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I can't do it because locahost is not hosted and thus not reachable from sharepoint. And as it is not reachable the proxy cannot be installed on the localhost...

Comment: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/